# Hibernate 6.3 creates bytea column type instead of geometry

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jts, hibernate-spatial

I basically encounter the same problem described in this post: [hibernate-spatial-4.0 creates bytea column type instead of geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34761606/hibernate-spatial-4-0-creates-bytea-column-type-instead-of-geometry)

According to the [hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#spatial) the type mapping of a jts Geometry object should be done automatically without any additional annotations required. However, i end up with the bytea type in my postgis database:
[Database result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U3Lz.png)

I use Spring boot 3.2, hibernate 6.3.1.Final and jts 1.19.
My model is defined as:

```
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
// ...

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
public class DwdPoiStation {

    /** the internal database id. */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // ...

    @Column
    private Geometry geom;

    /** the height. */
    @Column
    private float height;
}
```

And i have set the hibernate dialect accordingly:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema: public
```

For the database i use a kartoza/postgis:16-3.4 docker image.
The PostgreSQL jdbc driver version is 42.7.1.

What am i missing?

I tried one of the solution provided in the other post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60469891/10209352), checked my dependencies and used the latest jts library. I also searched online for other solutions, but were unable to even find a related problem using the hibernate 6.x version. Since the official documentation states that additional annotations are not required, i expect that i do not have to use properties like "columnDefinition" or annotations like @Type to make this work. It rather seems to be a version missmatch problem.

Comment: You don't need any annotations, but you must have the hibernate-spatial jar in the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the hibernate-spatial jar did not end up in my classpath. Now everything works like a charm. Thanks Karel for pointing that out!